# Eclipse Preferences does not save classpath variables

Tags: java, eclipse

I am running Eclipse neon IDE for Java Developers, however, this problem has been occurring on mars as well. Every time I open eclipse I am faced with the following two errors: 
- The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
- Unbound classpath variable: *I don't believe the name really matters*

The issue I am faced with is that every time I open eclipse I have to go to eclipse -> preferences -> java -> build path -> classpath variables
where I can then add the necessary variable and link the .jar I need. This fixes the problem. However, if I then close eclipse and re-open it, the variable is no longer there and the error reoccurs. I'm unsure of why my preferences aren't saved when I close eclipse.

Additionally, there is another class path variable that I no longer need, but if I remove it and reopen eclipse, it is there again. The location of that variable does even exist on my computer anymore. Any help or advice on this is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse stores the classpath variables in the file `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`. Maybe this file is not writable or will be automatically overwritten.

Comment: Okay, so I've gone into that file and manually fixed it. However, when I re-opened Eclipse it appears to have written over it again, returning it back to the incorrect state. For the time being I've just set the file to read-only so that it doesn't break itself. Is there something I can do to stop Eclipse from writing over it with old classpath variables?

Comment: Edit: Eclipse actually still overwrites the file, what can I do to stop it from automatically overwriting?

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with Oomph: disable both "Preference Recorder" and "Preference Synchronizer" in "Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Tasks". Or maybe the file is overwritten by a project builder or by a plug-in. I recommend to disable "Project > Build Automatically" first. If still the file will be overwritten then try to open your workspace with Eclipse SDK (http://eclip.se/an) only.

Comment: Okay, it's finally working. Thank you so much! When I went into the Preference Recorder submenu of Setup Tasks I saw that the only two variables that were checked were the one I was trying to setup, and the one I was trying to get rid of. By unchecking both of them I was able to remove the one I no longer wanted, and add the one I did want. Again, thank you so much. I have been dealing with this for almost half a year!

Comment: I've had the opposite experience. I just have a vanilla  Java version install with no workspaces and a couple of mainstream plugins. But I couldn't save preferences. Turning the Preference Recorder **on** for local recording seems to have fixed my issue.